# How to make right elements space-between?

Tags: css, reactjs

It doesn't work when I set `justify-content: space-between` on `rightContainer`, I want  Apple on the top and Sony on the bottom.

[image]

```
            <div className={styles.mainContainer}>
                <div className={styles.leftContainer}>
                    <div className={styles.profilePicture} />
                    <p className={styles.profileUsername}>Test Name</p>
                </div>
                <div className={styles.rightContainer}>
                    <p>Apple</p>
                    <p>Sony</p>
                </div>
            </div>
```

css

```
.mainContainer {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: cadetblue;
}

.leftContainer {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    text-align: left;
}

.rightContainer {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
    text-align: right;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Comment: For `justify-content` to work, the element must be a grid/flexbox column container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`justify-content: space-evenly` is only applicable to a flexbox. You can use a vertical flexbox to apply `space-evenly`.

```css
.mainContainer {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: cadetblue;
}

.leftContainer {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  text-align: left;
}

.rightContainer {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  text-align: right;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  display: flex; /*Create a flexbox*/
  flex-direction: column; /*Vertical flexbox*/
}
```

```html
<div class="mainContainer">
  <div class="leftContainer">
    <div class="profilePicture" />
    <p class="profileUsername">Test Name</p>
  </div>
  <div class="rightContainer">
    <p>Apple</p>
    <p>Sony</p>
  </div>
</div>
```